# How to continue this proof about Powersets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I need to prove the following statement:

Prove that if $a \in A$, then $P(A - \{a\}) \cap \{C \cup \{a\}\ |\ C \in P(A - \{a\})\} = \emptyset$, where $P(A)$ is the powerset of set $A$.

## My try:

Suppose $X \in P(A - \{a\}) \cap \{C \cup \{a\}\ |\ C \in P(A - \{a\})\} = \emptyset$
By the definition of $\cap$, we know that $X \in P(A - \{a\})$ and $X \in \{C \cup \{a\}\ |\ C \in P(A - \{a\})\}$.
By the definition powerset we also know that $X \subset A - {a}$ and $X \subset \{C \cup \{a\}\ |\ C \in P(A - \{a\})\}$
By negation law, we know that either $a \in X$ or $a \notin X$.

**Case 1**: Suppose $a \in X$.
By the definition of $\subseteq$, $a \in A - \{a\}$. Then, $a \in A$ and $a \notin \{a\}$, which is a contraditiction because $a \in \{a\}$.

**Case 2**: Suppose $a \notin X$.

---

This is where i lost myself. I can see that $a$ must be in the set $\{C \cup \{a\}\ |\ C \in P(A - \{a\})\}$, but I don't get how this leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\in\mathcal{P}(A\setminus\{a\})$, then $a\notin X$. If $X\in\bigl\{C \cup \{a\}\,|\,C \in\mathcal{P}(A \setminus \{a\})\bigr\}$, then $a\in X$. Therefore, no set can belong to both $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and to $\bigl\{C \cup \{a\}\,|\,C \in\mathcal{P}(A \setminus \{a\})\bigr\}$. In other words, $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\bigl\{C \cup \{a\}\,|\,C \in\mathcal{P}(A \setminus \{a\})\bigr\}=\emptyset$.

Comment: "If X∈P(A), then a∉X"
Sorry, but maybe you meant P(A - {a})? Also, how do you know $a \notin X$ in this case? I would have to prove it, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.